# Spring Convertor or Property editor for conversion of multiple request parameters into an Object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, type-conversion

Concrete example would be implementation of a Convertor/PropertyEditor for (2011, 11, 24, 8, 10, AM) request parameters to Date object ?

Let say that my UI uses a widget that uses 6 html form fields for calendar (2011, 11, 24, 8, 10, AM) - which is very inconvenient ..

Ideal solution would be if the parameter was only one - "yyyy:MM:dd:hh:mm:aa", @DateTimeFormat annotation was on the field and the WebDataBinder has been set with the DefaultConversionService + joda-time is on the classpath.

But I have to keep look and feel and use that widget. Also doing that conversion in handler method complicates validation a lot. Any idea how to do that without bothering in handler method ?

Answer (score 2):

If you create a custom wrapper object that have fields for each of the input parameters, having `public ... handlerMethod(InputDate date)` will populate it. Then, in the same class, you can have `toDateTime()` which will construct a `DateTime` based on the input.

You can also use a custom `WebArgumentResolver` and have a custom annotation, for example `@InputDate`, in your method signature.

Comment: that's what I'm doing now, the problem is the validation of this .. you'd first have to validate if those 2011, 11, 24, 8, 10, AM fields are present in the request parameters, then do the conversion manually, and then validate if the Date is correct ( greater then current time for instance)...If the conversion was happening behind the scenes I could validate everything at once

Comment: You can use javax.validation annotations on each field for some validation prior to the conversion

Comment: I can, but then I have to manually validate if the resulting Date is valid ... Or I can do some manual validation and find out from 2011, 11, 24, 8, 10, AM  if the date is valid...you know, it makes the handler ugly. I find myself needing this quite often recently

Comment: if you put he validation in the object itslef you won't have repreated code at least. I would change the format the UI sends the request params, but that seems not to be an option

Comment: Thanks Bozho, I leave this question open for now, I guess such a conversion is impossible. But it would be a nice feature request. Sometimes various parameters belong to the same 'context' and this would be useful.